# EF4.1 Code First : How to disable delete cascade for a relationship without navigation property in dependent entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

Let's say I have these two very basic entities:

```
public class ParentEntity
{
   public int Id;
   public virtual ICollection<ChildEntity> Childrens;
}

public class ChildEntity
{
   public int Id;
   public int ParentEntityId; // Foreign Key
   public virtual ParentEntity parent; // [NOTWANTED]
}
```

For some reasons, I don't want the ChildEntity to hold a reference back to his parent. I just want it to keep the ParentEntity id but nothing more.
Up until now, no problem, I just delete the [NOTWANTED] line, and everything works as expected.

My problem here is: how to disable the cascade delete in that specific case?

If I still had the parent navigation property it would be as easy as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ChildEntity>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.parent)
    .WithMany(p => p.Childrens)
    .WillCascadeOndelete(false)
```

However without the navigation property I have no idea how I can achieve to disable the cascade on delete (without disabling it globally of course, nor per table, but just for the relation).

What I have done right now is to set the foreign key as a nullable int, in order to disable the cascade on delete, but that's not pretty:

```
public int? ParentEntityId; // Foreign Key - nullable just to disable cascade on delete
```

How can I get it to work with fluent API? Think it should be possible.

Comment: you need .hasOne(ParentEntity)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You must configure it from the other side of the association:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ParentEntity>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Children)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentEntityId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: I had to change .WithRequired() to .WithRequired(c=>c.ParentEntity)

Comment: If you have a navigation property from the child to the parent then you can configure the cascade in the child mapping.